# Is it possible to add custom text in NSDateFormatter's format string?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

Suppose I want the date to look like this:

```
|1988|December|30|
```

How can add these to the dateFormatter or for that matter let the format be something like this:

```
30 in the month of December in the year of 1998
```

now for 1988,December and 30, I would like to use standard formats but I want the text I put to also accompany them.

specially in case of the above one where, in the format and pipes just come adjacent to the date format for date or month where there is no space between the format and the pipe.

Is any of this possible by just setting the format ?

Comment: http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/simple-methods-for-date-formatting-and.html

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can insert arbitrary text (enclosed in single quotes) in the date format, for example.

```
NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[fmt setDateFormat:@"dd' in the month of 'MMMM' in the year of 'yyyy"];
NSString *s = [fmt stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Result:

```
09 in the month of July in the year of 2013
```

Comment: I think you are missing one single quote there just before `yyyy`

Comment: No No. his answer was correct only I made an edit getting confused with last double quote.
I will change it again but SO says, my newer edit should be more detailed than previous to be accepted!

I think its fine now!

Comment: @redent84: The answer was edited by me and somebody else simultaneously, I will fix that.

Comment: one thing to mention is for other words, use '' to wrap them, I just revert it and get weird string

Comment: I need like Dec '15, So i write like                                           [dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"MMM'''yy"]; Then I am getting like Dec 'yy

Comment: [dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"MMM ''yy"];
 if i set like this. Its Worked. What is the reason ..?

Comment: @sivakrishna Do `MMM ''yy ` (two single quotes)

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46160390/how-to-add-characters-into-dateformatter/46160425?noredirect=1#comment79283081_46160390). Any reason you didn't place the single quotes around the strings?! You placed them next to the formatters which as a first timer (of using dates), it made your answer very confusing to me. Perhaps an edit would make it clear

Comment: @Honey: The single quotes are around the text to be inserted, `' in the month of '` and `' in the year of '`. It is not clear to me what you are suggesting.

Comment: the end result of it is `'MMMM'` which makes me think, for this to work you need to place single quotes next to `MMMM`. But you don't.

Comment: I was hoping that *"You can insert arbitrary text (enclosed in single quotes)"* makes it clear ...

Comment: facepalm!, What' your doing is actually necessary. Even the spaces need to be formatted like that.

Answer (score 7):

Swift Version:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat =  "EEEE' text here 'h:mm' and there 'a"
```

Answer (score 2):

**Updated for iOS 13, Swift 5, Xcode 11 and building on Martin R's answer**

```swift
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd' in the month of 'MMMM' in the year of 'yyyy"
let stringDate = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
print(stringDate)

// printed:
// 7 in the month of October in the year of 2019
```

P.S. If you wanted an apostrophe, then use: `''` directly inside the string. For example `"MMM d, ''yy"` -> `Nov 10, '19`

Extension:

If you wanted to add ordinal indicators too (ex. the 'th' after '13th'), you can actually do it inside the date formatter string.

So if you wanted `Nov 10th`, the code would be:

```swift
/// Get date.
let date = Date()

/// Get just the day of the date. 
let dayAsInt = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: date)

/// Init the formatter.
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

/// Set the format string.
/// Notice we include the 'MMM' to extract the month from the date, but we use a variable to get the 'th' part.
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM '\(dayAsInt.getStringWithOrdinalIndicatorIfPossible)'"
let formattedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

/// Will print out Nov 10th or Apr 1st or whatever.
```

Here's the extension I made to help:

```swift
/// This variable only adds the ordinal indicator if the Int that is calling this function can be converted to an NSNumber.
/// An ordinal indicator is the `rd` after `3rd` or the `st` after `1st`.
var getStringWithOrdinalIndicatorIfPossible: String {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .ordinal
    return formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: self)) ?? "\(self)"
}
```