# Prettier output with NSDateIntervalFormatterStyle

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Using *NSDateIntervalFormatterStyle* I can output a date range like:

- 6/30/14 - 7/11/14 for shortstyle
- Jun 30, 2014  - Jul 11, 2014 for mediumstyle
- June 30, 2014 - July 11, 2014 for longstyle

Is there a better way (other than to manually process this output) to output a pretty date range like :

- 6/30 - 7/11 for shortstyle
- Jun 30 - Jul 11 for mediumstyle (or even something like Jun 3-12) ?

Using such long *mediumstyle* takes a lot of the screen.

Comment: Review this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17542564/is-it-possible-to-add-custom-text-in-nsdateformatters-format-string

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `dateTemplate` property for instance of `NSDateIntervalFormatter` class, for example as following:

```
let formatter = NSDateIntervalFormatter()
formatter.dateTemplate = "dd/MM"
print(formatter.stringFromDate(date1, toDate: date2))
```

This will produce a string from date interval like this: `5/1 - 5/7`

Answer (score 0):

(currently) `NSDateIntervalFormatter` does not support custom dateFormats. But if your date differences are that trivial (i.e. no time, always on different dates, year doesn't matter) you can easily create your own subclass.

e.g.:

```
class DateIntervalFormatter: NSObject {
    lazy var dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = {
        let df = NSDateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = NSDateFormatter.dateFormatFromTemplate("MMM dd", options: 0, locale: nil)
        return df
    }()
    func stringFromDate(fromDate: NSDate, toDate: NSDate) -> String {
        let fromStr = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(fromDate)
        let toStr = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(toDate)
        return "\(fromStr) – \(toStr)"
    }
}
```

That yields `Jun 30 – Jul 11`, with this test code:

```
let date1 = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateWithEra(1, year: 2015, month: 6, day: 30, hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, nanosecond: 0)!
let date2 = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateWithEra(1, year: 2015, month: 7, day: 11, hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, nanosecond: 0)!

let customFormatter = DateIntervalFormatter()
let string = customFormatter.stringFromDate(date1, toDate: date2)
```