# How can I write a custom Date Format with string into it?

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdateformatter

silly question here:

I'm willing to write a custom date format in Swift for brazilian pattern, which will be something like:

```
"20 de Junho, 2017" // 20 of June, 2017
```

I was trying this pattern:

```
"dd de MMMM, yyyy"
```

But the `"de"` world is taken as a pattern as well. How can I say that this is a constant?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to add custom text in NSDateFormatter's format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17542564/is-it-possible-to-add-custom-text-in-nsdateformatters-format-string) – the date format syntax does not depend on the programming language (Swift or Objective-C)

Comment: True! Thanks. :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have to wrap it into quotes `'`, e.g.

```
"dd 'de' MMMM, yyyy"
```

From [Date Format Patterns](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns):

> Literal text, which is output as-is when formatting, and must closely match when parsing. Literal text can include:
>
> - Any characters other than A..Z and a..z, including spaces and punctuation.
> - Any text between single vertical quotes ('xxxx'), which may include A..Z and a..z as literal text.

You can also let the formatter generate the `de`:

```
let locale = Locale(identifier: "pt-BR")
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

let dayFormat = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: "d MMMM", options: 0, locale: locale)!

dateFormatter.dateFormat = dayFormat + ", yyyy"
dateFormatter.locale = locale

print(dateFormatter.string(from: Date())) // 7 de junho, 2017
```